# Carrossel CSS + JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, estou com um problema em um projeto onde o carrossel não consegue centralizar na div, **cada vez que passo para o próximo bloco de itens ele fica cada vez mais descentralizado**, como nas imagens:

[image: Antes de pular para o próximo]

[image: Após pular algumas vezes]

Perceba que a parte que contém a 'sombra', onde deveria ficar igual na primeira imagem, está descentralizando a cada click. Não consegui encontrar a causa.

O código utilizado:

JS:

```
let carosseis = document.getElementsByClassName('carossel-Container')

for(let i = 0; i < carosseis.length; i++){
  let carossel = carosseis[i]
  let btnBack = carossel.getElementsByClassName('BtnBack')[0]
  let btnNext = carossel.getElementsByClassName('BtnNext')[0]

  let itens = carossel.getElementsByClassName('item')
  let posicaoAnterior = 0
  let mover = posicaoAnterior + 100

  btnNext.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    mover = posicaoAnterior + 100

    for(let c = 0; c < itens.length; c++ ){

    itens[c].style.right=  mover + '%'

    posicaoAnterior = mover}
  })

  btnBack.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    mover = posicaoAnterior - 100

    for(let c = 0; c < itens.length; c++ ){

    itens[c].style.right=  mover + '%'

    posicaoAnterior = mover}

  })
}
```

CSS:

```
    section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 31vh;

  h2{
    font-size: clamp(0.9em, 1vw, 2em);
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
}

.carossel-Container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  //border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carossel-Slide{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 0 auto;
  //border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item{
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  flex: none;
  //border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  height: 21vh;
  //width: 241.6px;

  //width: 19.7385620915%;

  width: 280px;

  //width: 19.63%;

  transition: right 1s ease-out;

  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.btnCarossel{
  background: rgba(20,20,20,.5);
  width: 5%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btnCarossel:hover{
  background: rgba(20,20,20,.65);

  #seta{
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 0 1px #fff inset;
    transition: box-shadow 100ms;
  }
}



.BtnBack{
  left: 0;

  #seta{
    position: absolute;
  padding: 17%;
  box-shadow: 2px -2px 0 -1px #fff inset;
  border: solid transparent;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: box-shadow 100ms;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
}

.BtnNext{
  right: 0;

  #seta{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 17%;
    box-shadow: 2px -2px 0 -1px #fff inset;
    border: solid transparent;
    border-width: 0 0 2px 2px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: box-shadow 100ms;
  transform: rotate(225deg); 
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<section>
  <h2>Título</h2>
  <div class="carossel-Container">
    <div class="btnCarossel BtnBack disable">
      <span id="seta"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="carossel-Slide">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
      <div class="item">8</div>
      <div class="item">9</div>
      <div class="item">10</div>
      <div class="item">11</div>
      <div class="item">12</div>
      <div class="item">13</div>
      <div class="item">14</div>
      <div class="item">15</div>
      <div class="item">16</div>
      <div class="item">17</div>
      <div class="item">18</div>
      <div class="item">19</div>
      <div class="item">20</div>
      <div class="item">21</div>
      <div class="item">22</div>
      <div class="item">23</div>
      <div class="item">24</div>
      <div class="item">25</div>
    </div>
    <div class="btnCarossel BtnNext">
      <span id="seta"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um problema que esta acontecendo é que você esta soma 100% ao itens[c].style.right, esse valor, refere-se ao elemento pai (carossel-Slide) e não ao próprio item.

E como no elemento carossel-Slide, está usando um valor proporcional (width: 90%), E como o tamanho dos itens é fixo, dificilmente o tamanho do carossel será um múltiplo do width do = item

A solução que eu proponho é trocar os valores do width do item :

```
width: calc(25% - 0.2em);
```

o calculo é para compensar o tamanho da margin

Comment: Realmente, a sua solução funcionou, muito obrigado pelo ajuda.